# How to redirect the user to login page after sending password reset instructions in rails 3 using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, devise

I am using devise for authentication in Rails 3. I was able to redirect the user after signing in to the home page by creating a file named custom_failure.rb inside lib folder of my app and adding some code in application.rb.
Following is my custom_failure.rb code

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp

 def redirect_url
  root_path
 end

 def respond
  if http_auth?
   http_auth
  else
   redirect
  end
 end

end
```

Following is the application.rb code

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Please help me out by specifying which redirect function should I override in order to redirect the user to login page after the reset password mail is sent.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19402686/1125893
You can override `after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)` in `Devise::PasswordController`

```
def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
  root_path
end
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-URL-after-sending-reset-password-instructions

```
#routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => "passwords" }
```

Comment: Did the same..Still no success.

Comment: When you say 'not working' whats the exact behavior that you observe?
Any error message or stack trace you get ?

Comment: When I say its not working means I am being redirected to the default sign in page of devise after the send me reset password instructions button is pressed whereas I want to be redirected to the login page which is my home page actually.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
if http_auth?
   redirect_to http_auth
  else
   redirect_to redirect_url
  end
```

Comment: No its not working...Maybe I need to add another function but I don't know which function to add.

Answer (score 0):

In your application_controller.rb

```
protected
def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
  #set your path here
end
```

This is basically overriding the default devise method

Comment: Already tried this..Its not working.. Do we also need to pass something in place of (resource_name) ? I don't think so .. Is it ?